# .htaccess ReWrite for specific, existing directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to get an existing directory, /blog (as well as something like `/blog(/*)` ), to redirect to index.php along with any directory that doesn't exist, as the below currently does.

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^blog(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 404.shtml
```

I've tried about a thousand things so far and nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set allowoverride to all in httpd.conf?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this was the problem, but I moved the same htaccess file to a rackspace server, changed allowoverride to all and it works fine.

Comment: allowoverride is the option that enables you to use .htaccess files in the first place, otherwise Apache will just ignore them.

Comment: Ah, so then this was NOT the issue, then, as I had other things set and working in htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule blog /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: This seems to have the same effect as the code in my question. /blog still goes to the blog directory, and other non-existent directories go to index.

Comment: Ok, I forgot about the /blog problem, I thought the redirecting to index.php was the problem - my bad. I updated the answer.

Comment: Ok. So it should be that simple then. I'm getting a server error when I add that line. Could that be related to not having allowoverride set to all, as joe42 asked?

I'm on shared server without access to httpd.conf right now so I can't change that.

Comment: @dg988: That might be the problem. I tested it and it worked fine for me (allowOverride=ALL)